# PHP-HTML update mysql with input=text where POST['submit']

Tags: php, html, mysql, validation, post

I want to dispatch call from a courrier service.
I foreach in a HTML form, MySQL table with calls in status '1', so I can see witch calls still need to be dispatched.

When I put the 'MessagerID' in the input-text and push 'Dispatch' button I want that this 'CourseID' get updated with the 'MessengerID' and 'Status' goes to '0'.

Here's a little bit of code.(Not sanitazed yet...)

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE Status = :Status ORDER BY CourseRecu, Service";
    $query_params = array(
        ':Status' => 1);        
try
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Échec de la Requête: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$Courses = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

HTML Form:

```
    <?php foreach($Courses as $Course)
    {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="'. $Course['ID'] . '" value="' . $Course['ID'] . '"</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="CourseRecu" value="' . $Course['CourseRecu'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><textarea rows="3" cols="50" name="Depart">' . $Course['DepNom'] . '&#13;&#10;' . $Course['DepAdresse'] . '</textarea></td>';
    echo '<td>----></td>';
    echo '<td><textarea rows="3" cols="50" name="Destination">' . $Course['DestNom'] . '&#13;&#10;' . $Course['DestAdresse'] .  '</textarea></td>';
    echo '<td>
            <input type="text" name="MessagerID' . $Course['ID'] .'" value="' . $Course['MessagerID'] . '" /></td>';

    echo '<td><input type="submit" name="submit' . $Course['ID'] . '" value="Dispatch" /></td>';

    echo '</tr>';
    }
```

I know this is wrong,but m stuck there...

```
    if(!empty($_POST['submit' . $Course['ID']]))
{
    $query = "UPDATE courses SET 
            MessagerID = :MessagerID,
            Status = :Status
            WHERE ID = :ID" ;   
    $query_params = array(
    ':MessagerID' => $_POST['MessagerID' . $Course['ID']],
    ':Status' => 0,
    ':ID' => $_POST[$Course['ID']]); 

    try 
        { 
            // Execute the query to create the user 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        {
            die("La requête à échoué: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        }
}
```

I think I might be on the wrong track all the way and there probably a better way of doing this...
Thanks for taking the time! :-)

Comment: Where are you getting the $Course from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to suggest a few modifications.

1) Put a form around each set of input fields which correspond to a specific course, e.g.,

```
<?php foreach($Courses as $Course)
{
echo '<tr><form>';
echo '<td>
```

...

2) Don't name your submit based on the course ID but pass the course ID as a hidden field in the form.

```
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'. $Course['ID'].' />";
 echo '<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Dispatch" /></td>';

echo '</form></tr>';
```

This way you can check:

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['id'])
   $CourseID = $_POST['id'];
   //Do what you need to do to get the course here.
```

....

**Edit:** The same idea with renaming your submit applies to other input fields as well.

Comment: Yes! the '<form>' inside the 'foreach' works nice!
I was not so far away I See...
I really appreciate the time you took,
Thanks many times!